# How can I prevent ExtJs menu container from spilling out of the body?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using **ExtJs 4.1.1**. I am using body layout, the North region of which has a top toolbar. The top toolbar has a **splitButton** on it's extreme right.

**Problem**: Sometimes when the menu item has long text the container of menu items spills out of the body and it appears truncated.

[image]

I want to ensure that the menu text and the entire menu container is always visible. How can I achieve this?

**Update:** Can I configure the menu to unfold leftwards instead of right? This will take care of this particular situation.

Comment: Does the text need to be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, the text is dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried using a </br> statement in the text being displayed?

Comment: In order to see complete text, I have tooltips. I am really looking for a proper solution that would guarantee no spillover, especially when there is substantial real estate available on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

On the menu component, try adding:

```
listeners: {
     afterrender: function(component) {
         // Hide menu and then re-show so that alignment is correct.
         component.hide();
         component.show();
    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687551/extjs-incorrect-dropdown-menu-alignment)